# Combaining two array into single multi dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
status_name=Array("a","b","c","b","e","f");
status_id=Array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

How to combine these two arrays and to built multi dimensional array Expected Multidimensional array be like this

```
[["a", 1],["b", 2],["c", 3],["d", 4],["e", 5],["f", 6]]
```

Help me how to use above two array values and built my expected multidimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Myself and brought this solution, It might help some one

```
  status_name=Array("a","b","c","b","e","f");
    status_id=Array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Script:

```
            Values=[];
            for (i = 0; i < status_name.length; ++i)
            {
                Values[i] =Array(status_name[i], status_id[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you're including jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) in a similar fashion to Linus' answer:

```
var result      = [],
    status_name = ["a","b","c","b","e","f"],
    status_id   = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

result = $.map(status_name, function (el, idx) {
    return [[el, status_id[idx]]];
});
```

Looking at your variable names, I'd guess that your coming from a language (like PHP).  If that's the case, make sure you remember to declare local variables with the `var` keyword, otherwise you'll be polluting the global scope and you'll run into some hideous bugs in IE.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript has no buitin method for this, but you can easily write it yourself:

```
function zip(arrayA, arrayB) {
    var length = Math.min(arrayA.length, arrayB.length);
    var result = [];
    for (var n = 0; n < length; n++) {
        result.push([arrayA[n], arrayB[n]]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The name `zip` is chosen because a function that does something like this is often called `zip` in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
var combined = [], length = Math.min(status_name.length, status_id.length);
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    combined.push([status_name[i], status_id[i]]);
}
```

You could also use Array.prototype.map, but that's not supported in all browsers:

```
var combined = status_name.map(function(name, index) { return [name, status_id[index]] });
```

Comment: you meant that ? `combined.push([status_name[i], status_id[i]);`
a square bracket excess dude

Answer (score 1):

Using [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var status_name = ["a","b","c","b","e","f"],
    status_id = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    r = [];

r = $.map(status_name, function(n, i) {
    return [[n, status_id[i]]]; 
});
```

Note the difference between `return [[n, status_id[i]]]` and `return [n, status_id[i]]`. Using the former will result in a 2d array while using the latter will result in a 1d array.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function array_combine (keys, values) {
    // Creates an array by using the elements of the first parameter as keys and the elements of the second as the corresponding values  
    // 
    // version: 1102.614
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_combine
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // *     example 1: array_combine([0,1,2], ['kevin','van','zonneveld']);
    // *     returns 1: {0: 'kevin', 1: 'van', 2: 'zonneveld'}
    var new_array = {},
        keycount = keys && keys.length,
        i = 0;

    // input sanitation
    if (typeof keys !== 'object' || typeof values !== 'object' || // Only accept arrays or array-like objects
    typeof keycount !== 'number' || typeof values.length !== 'number' || !keycount) { // Require arrays to have a count
        return false;
    }

    // number of elements does not match
    if (keycount != values.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < keycount; i++) {
        new_array[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }

    return new_array;
```

---

Reference
 - [arr combine](http://www.bitrepository.com/equivalent-of-phps-array_combine-function.html)
 - [array combine](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_combine:307)