# Combine two normal arrays to create key:value pair array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays like so:

`arr1 = ['one','two','three']`

`arr2 = ['1','2','3']`

Is there a way with jQuery to combine them so the output would be like:

`arr3 = ['one':'1', 'two':'2', 'three':'3']`

Comment: That's not a valid array! Use an object: `{ key: value }`

Comment: Why does everyone beg for using jQuery?

Comment: Anyway, do you desire an object (per Vohuman) or  `[[k1,v1],[k2,v2],..]` or even `["k1:v1","k2:v2",..]` or..?

Comment: Thanks user2864740... Just something Im working on. got what i needed below from Scott Stensland

Comment: You are looking for [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#object), **not jQuery**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking to create an object (associative array) if so

```
var arr1 = ['one','two','three'];

var arr2 = ['1','2','3'];

var combo_obj = {};

arr1.forEach(function(element, index) {

    combo_obj[element] = arr2[index];
});

console.log(combo_obj);
```

here is its output

```
{ one: '1', two: '2', three: '3' }
```

Comment: Yes, your correct. I was looking to create an object . Apologies for the typo thank you...

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = {};
for(i=0; i< arr1.length && i < arr2.length; ++i){
    result[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check here: [Combaining two array into single multi dimensional array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258086/combaining-two-array-into-single-multi-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Here is an example:

```
arr3=[];
for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; ++i)
{
    arr3[i] = Array(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
}
```